# How to get the count and row list in a single query for pagination?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, query-optimization

How to get the `count` and row list in a single query for `pagination` in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee;
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employer_id = ? OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25;
```

Instead of making 2 requests to get the count and rows, Is there a way to do it in a single query?

I have tried the following,

```
SELECT 
    e.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee AS e WHERE e.employer_id = ?) 
FROM employee AS e 
WHERE e.employer_id = ? 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25;
```

but it's inefficient, it requires the same input twice and the `count` will be calculated in each row.

I there any better way or built-in function to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window function:

```
select *, count(*) over()
from employee e
where e.employer_id = ? 
offset 0 
limit 25
```

Or if you want to stick to your version, you can leverage cte:

```
with e_cnt as (
    select count(*) cnt
    from employee
    where e.employer_id = ? 
)
select *, (select cnt from e_cnt)
from employee e
where e.employer_id = ? 
offset 0 
limit 25
```

Then you know it's evaluated once.

Comment: Thanks, @Andronicus. `CTE WITH` query gives better performance over `WINDOWS` function.